# potted cherry tree-lost leaves

Tags: trees, cherries

We wintered a potted cherry tree outdoors, but brought it in during the month of March. 
It leafed beautifully, but we were gone for 2 weeks and I fear it didn't receive enough light. As a result, it has lost it leaves.
Is there any hope for this tree?

Comment: Welcome! Sometimes a picture helps - could you please [edit]?

Comment: I;d also ask you you to add whether its a fruiting or ornamental cherry,and why you decided to bring it indoors?